# Read queries in cql when all clustering columns are not available

Tags: cassandra, cql

In cql, when we write read queries we need to provide columns in same order as they are mentioned in primary key definition, and all of them must be present. But how to write query if we don't have values available for some of the clustering columns.

For example, if primary key is defined as primary key((state), city, name) for a table containing records for users with their state, city and name as part of primary key, then how to write query to find all users with a given name from a state irrespective of their city?
Something like

```
Select * from USERS where state ='....', name='....';
```

won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. Create a query table alongside the original table keyed on `PRIMARY KEY ((state),name)`.
2. Invoke the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive on the above query, which filters on only `state` and `name`.

While the use of `ALLOW FILTERING` is normally discouraged (and with good reason), it's not nearly as bad in *this* case.  By specifying `state`, you've given the query the ability to locate the node which contains the data.  Yes, you'll still be "filtering" through data in a non-performant way, but at least it won't be across multiple nodes.

Comment: So if in my application there are usecases which are not covered by initial query design, I would need to keep adding such tables/materialized views.

Comment: @Mandroid yes, that is the accepted practice.

Comment: @Mandroid - I would avoid using the materialized views for this though, add tables instead.